# Некорректная работа событий (JS) в последнем IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет.

Кто подскажет, почему в последнем IE не корректно работает представленный скрипт. А точнее события в IE отрабатывают по другому.

Во всех браузерах при изменение радио кнопок, срабатывает ТОЛЬКО событие `change`, а в IE ВСЕГДА `change` и `click`. Можно наблюдать в консоли.

Заранее благодарен за помощь!

**Весь необходимой код, тут:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owGQmN

```
$('.js-calculator').each(function () {
  var $wrapper      = $(this);
  var $radioButtons = $wrapper.find('input[type="radio"]');



  $wrapper.on('change', function () {
    console.log('change');
    var radios = $wrapper.find('input[type="radio"]');

    radios.removeClass('checked');
    radios.filter(':checked').addClass('checked');
  });



  $wrapper.on('click', '.checked', function () {
    console.log('click');
    $(this).removeClass('checked');
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

Comment: Что значит `измените радио кнопку`? каким образом? что должно быть в консоли...или наоборот не должно? в какой версии IE? Опишите по-человечески проблему словами....и зачем тут в цикле вешаются события?

Comment: Значит сделать "change". Посмотрите отработку событий. Только в IE отрабатывает change и click одновременно. Написано же в заголовке, что последняя версия IE. Где вы тут события в цикле увидели!? Есть название модуля, внутри которого уже события.

Comment: А последняя это какая? Некоторые Edge называют последней версией IE, а некоторые 11.... `Где вы тут события в цикле увидели` - а `each` по твоему что, просто красивое словечечко?... без циклов. в нормальном варианте `$('.js-calculator').on('change','input[type="radio"]', function () {
   console.log('change');   
});

$('.js-calculator').on('click','input[type="radio"]', function () {
    console.log('click');    
});` отрабатывает как должно по два события, собсн

Comment: Последняя версия IE - это последняя версия IE. Edge тут причем... А если у меня на странице 10 js-calculator? Для каждого модуля свои события, которые вешаются по 1 разу.

Comment: Открою секрет, то, что вы написали - это тоже самое... И работать будет так-же не корректно в IE.

Comment: Открою секрет - я проверял, работает, прикинь

Comment: Спасибо за "помощь"... Остановитесь :)

Comment: Ты лучше в вопросе уточни что ты называешь `отрабатывают по другому`? Какое поведение ты ожидаешь увидеть во всех браузерах. только click или только change или оба сразу? Может в итоге это как раз IE шикарен... Пока из твоего вопроса понятно лишь то, что что-то не так, а по коду кажется, что это ты что-то не так делаешь

Comment: Написал более детально.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, В хроме: кликаешь радиобаттон, он отмечается, срабатывает обработчик `change`, но не срабатывает обработчик `click`; кликаешь ещё раз - срабатывает `click` и чекнутость снимается. В IE (у меня IE11 Win7 x64) при первом клике выполняются оба обработчика (сначала `change`, затем `click`), поэтому чекнутость снимается немедленно и получается, что радиобаттоны вообще не работают. Как это можно не заметить? о_О